# How to perform concurrent streaming upserts into Azure Synapse Analytics

Tags: azure-synapse

We have an application that reads from a message bus and upserts into Azure Synapse Analytics. There are multiple instances of the application and each instance is multi-threaded. Each upsert could have an upwards of a few hundred entries and the target tables could have a few million entries.

Synapse does not support MERGE operations. We are seeking a solution better than two-step DELETE - INSERT. We considered solutions involving table joins and followed by table renames such as [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-ctas#replace-merge-statements).

However, all these solutions have performance and/or concurrency issues.

Could you please recommend a solution to upsert into Azure Synapse Analytics from concurrent data streams.

Many thanks!